# imagefttext() no t working have any idea?

Tags: php

this is the exmaple:

```
            $im = imagecreatetruecolor(300, 100);
            $red = imagecolorallocate($im, 0xFF, 0x00, 0x00);
            $black = imagecolorallocate($im, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00);

            // Make the background red
            imagefilledrectangle($im, 0, 0, 299, 99, $red);

            // Path to our ttf font file
            $font_file = 'Oswald-Regular.TTF';

            // Draw the text 'PHP Manual' using font size 13
            imagefttext($im, 13, 0, 105, 55, $black, $font_file, 'PHP Manual');

            // Output image to the browser
            header('Content-Type: image/png');

            imagepng($im);
            imagedestroy($im);
```

this is a resultate: 
Just this

�PNG  IHDR,d�c�� pHYs���+/IDATx���1 �0�� ��}:��[�v&�� !fB��b&�� !fB��b&�� !fB��b&�� !fB��b&�� !fB��b&�� !fB��b&�� !fB��b&�� !fB��b&�� !fB��b&�� !fB��b&�� !fB��b&�� !fB��b&�� !fB��b&�� !fB��b&�� !fB��b&�� !fB��b&�� !fB��b&�� !fB��b&�� !fB��b&�� !fB��b&�� !fB��b&�� !fB��b&�� !fB��b&�� !fB��b&�� !���ǶyXIEND�B`�

Comment: code works fine and generates a red rectangle ~ I had to modify the font path to get the text to appear though

Comment: I use OS ubuntu, and this code don't generate nothing i used all similar function, but nothing.

Comment: Have you tried with standard integers rather than hex for the colours?

Answer (score 0):

@Klevis Cipi - this is the code I ran and it produced the image. There is no output anywhere before you call `imagepng` is there??

```
<?php

    $sText='Stackoverflow';
    $fontsize=18;

    $oImg   = imagecreatetruecolor(300, 100);
    $oRed   = imagecolorallocate($oImg, 255, 0, 0);
    $oBlack = imagecolorallocate($oImg, 0, 0, 0);

    // Make the background red
    imagefilledrectangle($oImg, 0, 0, 300, 100, $oRed);

    // Path to our ttf font file
    $font_file = 'c:/wwwroot/inc/fonts/arial.ttf';

    imagefttext($oImg, $fontsize, 0, 50, 55, $oBlack, $font_file, $sText );

    // Output image to the browser
    header('Content-Type: image/png');
    imagepng($oImg);
    imagedestroy($oImg);

?>
```